# Accessing a database with a php script from Unity mobile game

Tags: unity, c#, databases, php

So I am attempting to keep track of some user data in my game that I am creating in Unity 3d. I am using Unity's WWW class to do this. I am following this tutorial: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores

I am not sure why but I keep getting a 404 error even though the file is on the server. I am using godaddy to host my website and I have the php script that I am trying to access in there so that it can use it to query the database. I am using "http://www.mysite/myscript.php?" followed by the values that I want to push to the database, as the tutorial shows to do.

No matter what I do I end up with a 404 and it doesn't make any sense as I know that it is there in the path I am attempting to connect to. If I type out the path to the php file in a browser it will take me to a page that gives an error about the hash not existing (since I am not passing one unless it is in my game) so I know that the file is there.

**3/18/16**

Here is my php script to add the values to the database.

```
<?php
    $server = "MyServersIP";
    $user = "MyUser";
    $pass = "MyPassword";
    $db = "MyDB";

    $conn = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);

    mysql_select_db($db);

    $Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Username'], $db);
    $Fuel = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Fuel'], $db);
    $IAPCar1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['IAPCar1'], $db);
    $IAPCar2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['IAPCar2'], $db);
    $Score = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Score'], $db);
    $Level = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Level'], $db);
    $Wins = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Wins'], $db);
    $Losses = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Losses'], $db);
    $Ads = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Ads'], $db);
    $LicensePlate = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['LicensePlate'], $db);
    $hash = $_GET['hash'];

    $secretKey = "mySecretKey";

    $real_hash = md5($Username . $Fuel . $IAPCar1 . $IAPCar2 . $Score .     $Level . $Wins . $Losses .
    $Ads . $LicensePlate . $hash);
    if ($real_hash == $hash)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Player values (NULL, '$Username', '$Fuel', '$IAPCar1', '$IAPCar2',
        '$Score', '$Level', '$Wins', '$Losses', '$Ads', '$LicensePlate');";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the code I use to call the php script:

```
public string setValues = "http://www.mysite.com/Set_Values.php?";
private string secretKey = "SecretKeyFromThePhpScript";
public void SetValues(string username, int fuel, bool iapCar1, bool iapCar2, int score,
    int level, int wins, int losses, bool ads, string licensePlate, bool firstTime)
{
    string hash = Md5Sum(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}", username, fuel, iapCar1, iapCar2,
        score, level, wins, losses, ads, licensePlate, secretKey));
    string url = string.Format("{0}username={1}&fuel={2}&IAPCar1={3}&IAPCar2={4}&Score={5}&Level={6}" +
        "&Wins={7}&Losses={8}&Ads={9}&LicensePlate={10}&FirstTime={11}&hash={12}", setValues, username, fuel, iapCar1, iapCar2,
        score, level, wins, losses, ads, licensePlate, firstTime, secretKey);

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
}
```

Comment: Is your file really hosted at www.mysite?

Comment: @Almo Yes I put the php file in the fileague manager and I can't type the path into a browser and get an error since I don't add the hash for the file.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. Are you putting literally "mysite"? What's "fileague"? What do you mean "hash for the file"? This is only getting more confusing.

Comment: @Almo No I am putting the actual address to the site. And that should have said file manager but my phone "corrected" me lol. The hash is the secret key used to confirm the calls are being made from the game. You,can see that in the link to the tutorial I am using.

Comment: OK, at this point you should include some of your code (only the relevant bits) in the question itself. External links have a habit of dying.

Comment: @Almo Idk how that will help figure out why the php script is coming up as not found but I updated the post with some code.

Comment: Looking at your call to the php script, I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @Almo I didn't think it was the call since it directly reflects the tutorial I have been following. It makes me think that maybe I need to have the php script in a different folder in my godaddy file manager.

Comment: Hmm, did you look at the httpd log to see what files were requested? (And could not be served because not found.)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I just took a look and I see that it is trying to get the right script. I can see all the values that I pass as part of the url as well. Not sure what is going on. The only thing is that it says GET /SetValues.php and then there is a line break and the whole string that I add to the url is there without the question mark.

Comment: If you were to try to pass the same data _with_ the question mark, maybe you have an issue with the request, if there is no question mark showing in the log when called form Unity, but there is one when you call it manually, I think you have an issue around there...

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt So I shouldn't have the question mark in the url after SetValues.php like the tutorial shows?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Because without that how would it know where to break the actual path from what is being passed?

Comment: Exactly, it it works with the _?_ when you do it manually, Unity should send it _also_ with the _?_.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt When I debug and copy the full url that is being passed in and paste it into a browser it shows up like it doesn't exist. If I type in just the url to the php scrip itself then it finds it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37193/discussion-between-alexandre-vaillancourt-and-saboehnke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue turned out to be that I had a typo in my url that I used. Also I needed to change $db to $conn where I am getting the values and assigning them to variables.